# Vertical align image next to multiline text

Tags: html, css

Is it posible to vertical align multiline text next to a image. I tried this: http://jsfiddle.net/lassebjensen/4fv6u/3/

```
#holder {
      vertical-align: middle; 
      display:table-cell; 
}

.img-left{ 
      float:left; 
      padding-left:35px;
      vertical-align:middle;
      margin-right:70px;
}

.text {
    font-size:24px;
        overflow:hidden;
 }
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="holder" >  
      <img class="img-left" src="http://i.cdn.turner.com/cnn/.e/img/3.0/global/header/intl/CNNi_Logo.png" /> 
      <p   class="text" >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec eu neque nec lectus egestas hendrerit. Sed sed felis tempor, pharetra nunc eu, molestie lectus. Aenean auctor quam nisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec eu neque nec lectus egestas hendrerit. Sed sed felis tempor, pharetra nunc eu, molestie lectus. Aenean auctor quam nisi. 
      </p>
</div>
```

Kind regards

Comment: do you mean put the image in the middle of the text?

Comment: use google mate...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524029/vertical-align-an-image-and-a-multiline-text or https://www.google.co.in/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=Vertical+align+image+next+to+multiline+text&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=vDvIUpK2KsyXiQeokoHwDQ

Comment: @jmore009: Yes put the image in the middle of the text without

Kind regards

Comment: @NoobEditor: I did hours of search. In my search I stumbleupon  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524029/vertical-align-an-image-and-a-multiline-text. My problem with that example is that I do not know the size of my images

Comment: @user3160735: check my answer.. there was a small mistake and i have edited ..!!