# Image beside multiline text in 'vertical-align: middle' with fluid layout (Pure CSS from YUI)

Tags: css, yui-pure-css

I want an image beside a multiline text (*usually two lines*) with vertical-align: middle.

When it's just one line, everything is ok with `vertical-align: middle` in the image style, but when the text has more than one line, the mess begins.

`jsfiddle` ==> **http://jsfiddle.net/QZhG7/1/**

[image]

Comment: 2 years late and I don't know why I wrote "two long".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524029/vertical-align-an-image-and-a-multiline-text), but it needed some adjustments to work fine with Pure CSS in a fluid layout.

First, I needed to create a `div` around image.

.

Was this:

```
<img src="image.png">
```

Become this:

```
<div class="image"> <img src="image.png"> </div>
```

.

And CSS:

```
.pure-u-1-3 { 
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;    
}
.image, span {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.image {
   width: 50px
}
```

Tha following code: `.image { width: 50px }` is needed because Pure CSS will "resize" the image to a smaller size. Remove this line and watch what happened in desktop/tablet version.

.

For the final result, visit `jsfiddle` ==> **http://jsfiddle.net/QZhG7/3/**

For more information, visit the [original Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524029/vertical-align-an-image-and-a-multiline-text).