# How to vertically align image and text in table cell?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, css-tables

I'm trying to get the text to be on the right side and vertically center aligned with the image. How can I do that?

My current code:

```html
<div style="display: table;">
  <div style="display: table-cell;"><img src="//dummyimage.com/100"></div>
  <div style="display: table-cell;">text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Below the image? Can't recreate it with your current code: https://jsfiddle.net/31yoxzfb/

Comment: I don't think it's below it's probably just bottom aligned, try adding `vertical-align: top;` or `middle` to the cells.

Comment: @Pangloss, yes thank you that did it.

Comment: @TimAkgayev Nice to hear that, I just posted it as an answer with more details.

Comment: [Possible duplicate of Vertical align an image and a multiline text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524029/vertical-align-an-image-and-a-multiline-text)

Answer (score 9):

use CSS3 [Flexible Box Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes):

from the documentation:

> providing for the arrangement of elements on a page such that the
> elements behave predictably when the page layout must accommodate
> different screen sizes and different display devices. For many
> applications, the flexible box model provides an improvement over the
> block model in that it does not use floats, nor do the flex
> container's margins collapse with the margins of its contents.

your example with centered text to the right would look like this

```css
#pageElement{display:flex; flex-wrap: nowrap; align-items: center}
```

```html
<div id="pageElement">
  <div> <img src="//dummyimage.com/100"> </div>
  <div> text </div>
</div>
```

I found this [cheat-sheet](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) very helpful and browser compatibility you find [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

Comment: This actually seems like the best way to go, however my text is now at the top not center. Why?

Comment: if you clear all css styles which could interfere with `#pageElement` and it's inner `div`, it must look like the example above

Answer (score 2):

In table cell, the default value of `vertical-align` is `baseline`. You can change that to `middle` for center align. Read more about it on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align).

```css
.table {
  display: table;
}
.table > div {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div><img src="//dummyimage.com/100"></div>
  <div>text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use td, tr and table.

```
<body>
<table>
   <tr width="100%;">
      <td width="50%;" valign="bottom">
      <img style="width:100%" src="https://s.w.org/images/home/screen-themes.png?1"/> </td>
      <td width="50%;" align="center" valign="center">  text dddddddddddd  </td>
   </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

See JsFiddle for example:
https://jsfiddle.net/bndr6x4y/1/