# Unable to center div properly

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to center a div inside of a div. Instead, its shaded to the right. I have tried all combinations of positions. I tried everything I found in other threads and have not been able to fix this. This is how it looks: https://jsfiddle.net/L13qa1tr/

`content_page.html:`

```
<div id="wrapper">
      <div id="main-content" class="container">
          <h1 class="text-center">This is a test, remove before release.This is a test, remove before release.This is a test, remove before release.</h1>
      </div>
</div>
```

Relevant CSS, `content_page.css:`

```
body {
  font-family: 'Lora', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  top: 61px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: white;
  background-color: black; }

html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; }

h1 {
  font-family: 'Cabin', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin: 0 0 35px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase; }

#wrapper{
    background-color: #555555;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#main-content {
    position: relative;
    top: 32px;
    left: 88px;
    right: 88px;
    bottom: 32px;
    background-color: #E1E1E1;
    height: auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

I can post any other information needed, just let me know. If anyone can point me in the right direction that would be great. The part that also confuses me is that the width of the inner div should be 100% so it would make sense if it took up all of the space, but in this case it isn't taking up enough.

Comment: check and adapt: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41656403/2275490

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot of unnecessary code in there. I removed a lot of it.

The margin: 0 auto; needs to be placed inside the #main-content to center it instead of the #wrapper.
I changed the width to show you that it works.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Lora', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  top: 61px;
  color: white;
  background-color: black; }

h1 {
  font-family: 'Cabin', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin: 0 0 35px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase; }

#wrapper{
    background-color: #555555;
    padding: 5px;
}
#main-content {
    position: relative;
    top: 32px;
    background-color: #E1E1E1;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
      <div id="main-content" class="container">
          <h1 class="text-center">This is a test, remove before release.This is a test, remove before release.This is a test, remove before release.</h1>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me clear the clutter, I used a mix of your answer with davvv's calc solution to allow me to keep my set sides. But I also needed to use container-fluid instead of container.

Without the class change, any change in width would not reflect (I suspect Bootstrap was overwriting my changes)

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to center your `#main-content` div, here is how you can do it.

```
#main-content {
    position: relative;
    width: 80%;
    width:calc( 100% - 88px - 88px);
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #E1E1E1;
    height: auto;
}
```

The `calc` method is just using your left and right peramters. You can remove this and just use the percent, which will still align it in the middle.

To center a `div` you need to set a width, followed by automatic margins on the left and right:

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto
```

See [this](https://jsfiddle.net/5hfuvgry/) updated fiddle.

Comment: I accepted Michelle's answer. Sorry :( I implemented her change first, and then changed the container class as container-fluid works, but container doesn't. Thank you for the calc() solution, that helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Well that was a part of your issue, that you were moving the `div` using

`position:relative` and adding `top,left,right` and `bottom`.

Instead all you are supposed to add is `margin:auto`.
Width is reduced just for bring the content in the center.

```
#main-content {
  width:600px;
  margin:auto;
  background-color: #E1E1E1;
}
```

Comment: Not my issue unfortunately. See @MichelleCantin answer.